# ngx-emoji-mart backgroundImageFn directive

Tags: angular, emoji

I'm using ngx-emoji-mart with Angular 6, I'm trying to use `backgroundImageFn` directive to load the emoji sheet locally as the documentation of [ngx-emoji-mart](https://github.com/TypeCtrl/ngx-emoji-mart)  said like this:

```
<emoji-mart
[backgroundImageFn]="((set,sheetsize)=> 'emoji-picker.png'")"
>
</emoji-mart>
```

But the syntax error, so I tried to do this in my ts

```
   @Input()
        backgroundImageFn: Emoji['backgroundImageFn'] = 
                           (set: 'emojione', sheetSize: 20,) => { `emoji-picker.png` }
```

and then retry with

```
 <emoji-mart
    [backgroundImageFn]="backgroundImageFn"
    >
 </emoji-mart>
```

Nothing change, the emojipicker still load the sheet from unpkj.com not from my localhost. I went through the library to see how can I override this function and stop calling unpkj.com.

```
export interface Emoji {
   ...
   ...
    backgroundImageFn: (set: string, sheetSize: Emoji['sheetSize']) => string;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import interface:

   `import { Emoji } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/ngx-emoji/emoji.component'`
2. Realize interface in your code behind:

   `public backgroundImage: Emoji['backgroundImageFn'] = (set: string, sheetSize: number) => this.yourImg;`
3. Put it in your container:

   `<emoji-mart [backgroundImageFn]="backgroundImage"> </emoji-mart>`